# Installing Memgraph on Debian 12 (bookworm)

Tags: memgraphdb

I've tried to install Memgraph on Debian 12 (on Intel based server, not a cloud deployment). I'm getting package dependency issues when I try to install it. This were my steps:

1. Install Debian 12
2. Follow the instructions from https://memgraph.com/docs/getting-started/install-memgraph/debian
3. `use apt-get install -f` to install dependencies
4. `apt-get` uninstalls Memgraph because some dependencies are not installable

If I do a roll back to Debian 11 it all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that at the moment Debian 12 is not officially supported. Supported distributions are listed at https://memgraph.com/docs/getting-started/install-memgraph/direct-download-links. At the moment Debian 10 and Debian 11 listed.